# Isn't "Different between" wrong?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I thought `Different between` is wrong because `different` does not explain `difference` (That's just my knowledge), but sometimes, I saw used `Different between`. Isn't it wrong? If so, why?

I have tried to read [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/words-language/difference-between-difference-and-different/), but I have not read [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/words-language/difference-between-difference-and-different/) well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words '**different**' and '**difference**' both show some qualities that are not the same or alike.

The difference (for want of a better word) between the two is the part of speech they represent.

'different' is an adjective, and is used to modify a noun. For example.

> - The two brothers could not have been more different. (modifies 'brothers')
> - We need to try an entirely different approach. (modifies 'approach')
> - They met with each other on several different occasions. (modifies 'occasions')

The word 'difference' on the other hand, is a noun, and is used to specify the extent or quality of dissimilarity or contrasts **between** two things, situations, or entities.

> - She knows the difference between right and wrong.
> - There's no difference between the two houses. They look exactly the same.
> - There's a big difference in price.

In other words, 'difference' tries to bring about a comparison between two or more items, whereas 'different' is usually a word of certainty where we just declare a thing to be unmatched to something else.

So yes, '**different between**' *to make a comparison* would be incorrect. However, a sentence along the lines of:

> Something is **different between** you two today.

would be correct, because 'different' modifies 'something', rather than trying to make a comparison between the two people in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

For **difference**, the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/difference) defines two relevant meanings:

> A point or way in which people or things are dissimilar - **property**
> *there are differences **between** men and women*

> [mass noun] The state or condition of being dissimilar - **state**
> *Judging by my experience of American culinary habits, they will notice no difference **from** home cooking.*

For **different**, The [Oxford Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20160928090959/https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/different) the following definition:

> Not the same as another or each other; unlike in nature, form, or quality - **state**
> *the car's different **from** anything else on the market*

---

**State**

When we talk about two things being the same or not the same, this is a state: we can do this with either **difference** or **different**, together with the prepositions [**from**, **to** or **than**](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043846/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/different-from-than-or-to). In the same way, we would say

> America is separate **from** Europe - **state**

---

**Property**

When we talk about a property- the quality or extent of the difference between two things, we can only use **difference**, together with the preposition **between**. In the same way, we would say

> There is 3000 miles **between** America and Europe - **property**

**Different between** is therefore not generally valid.

Note that it is possible to construct a sentence containing **difference between**, for example when **between** defines a range that qualifies when  some other thing was different.

> The situation was different between 1939 and 1944.